# NPE: "println needs a message" AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am doing an AsyncTask and it is throwing a NPE exception when trying to execute doInBackground().  I've looked for answers here and on Google, as far as passing a null into the Logcat and feel like I've handled the error.  What am I doing wrong

```
    private static class UpdateSequenceNumbers extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        int RecID = 0;
        String values = "";
        //select rd.RecID   from T_ResultsSummary rs
        //inner join T_ResultsSummaryHistory rsh on rsh.LocalSumID = rs._id
        //inner join T_ResultsDetail rd on rd.LocalHisID = rsh._id
        //where Value = '-1' and rd.Comments = 'AutoNum' and rd.Active = 1 and SurveyID in (1,2,3,4) and
        //rd.RecID <> -1
        Cursor c  = DataBaseConnector.query(params[0]);
        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do { 
                     logMessage("Begin Sequence Numbers Update");
                     RecID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("RecID"));
                     values = String.valueOf(RecID);
                     try {
                        logMessage("Stored Proc: " + params[1] + "; Values: " + values);

                        SoapPrimitive response = callProcServiceForScalar(params[1], values);

                        String sResponse = decryptIfNeeded(response.toString());

                        logMessage("Stored Proc Response: " + sResponse);

                        if (sResponse != null) { 
                            if (!sResponse.equals("")) {
                                if (sResponse.contains("Error=")) {
                                    insertSyncError(sResponse.toString(), params[1], values);
                                    return false;

                                }
                                //this is the happy path where all the action happens
                                else { 
                                    String sql = "Update "+ params[2] + " Set Value =  " + sResponse + " "//
                                               + "Where RecID = " + String.valueOf(RecID);
                                    DataBaseConnector.execSQL(sql);
                                }
                            } else {
                                insertSyncError("Blank Response", params[1], values);
                                return false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            insertSyncError("Null Response", params[1], values);
                            return false;
                        }
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         //e.printStackTrace();
                         String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"Stored Proc Failed":e.getMessage();
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                         insertSyncError(err, "");
                        return false;
                     }
                } while (c.moveToNext());
                logMessage("End Sequence Numbers Update");
            }

            c.close();
            c = null;

        }


        return true;



    }
}

    private static void insertSyncError(String errorText, String sqlStatement) {
    syncSuccessful = false;
    GlobalVars.syncError = errorText != null ? errorText : "Error Occured";
    logMessage("Error Text: " + errorText);
    logMessage("Error SQL Statement: " + sqlStatement);

    if (errorText == null) {
        errorText = "";
    }

}
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at com.assistek.ediary.EDiaryDataSync$AllSync.doInBackground(EDiaryDataSync.java:183)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at com.assistek.ediary.EDiaryDataSync$AllSync.doInBackground(EDiaryDataSync.java:1)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-28 16:34:45.010: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):     ... 3 more
```

Comment: What is line 183 of `EDiaryDataSync`?

Comment: where is logMessage() implemented?

Comment: Log.<severity>(TAG, null) is getting called somewhere. You should be able to follow your logcat trace to the source.

Comment: The error is in the **AllSync** class. Looks like you posted the code for the wrong AsyncTask?

Comment: @matlash - Actually, it's in this class, it's being called from AllSync.

Comment: Check the returned value of `params[1]` and `sResponse` - because either one of those could return null. Say, if `sResponse` is null, then doing this `sResponse.toString()` will cause a NullPointerException.